# Return to MVC controller after posting to Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm posting some data to an web api controller method from an MVC controller with this method..

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendDataToApi (List<TogglRow> input)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:****/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/service", input);
            //if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            //{
            //    var resultUri = response.Headers.Location;
            //}
            return response;
        }
    }
```

This is the Web Api method i'm posting to..

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request, List<Dagsrapport> value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var rapporter = value.ToList();
            //send rapporter to DB
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            return response;
        }
        return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

Now, the post works fine and i'm returning HttpStatusCode.OK. But i'm not beeing redirected back to the method i'm performing the post from (SendDataToApi()). I'm beeing returned back to the page from wich the post was triggered. I can see the page is working (waiting for localhost..) but nothing happens.

I should probably mention that this is two separate projects (MVC & WebApi), but in the same solution.

What am i missing?

**EDIT**  - **Solved**

The problem I had was due to the method that ran the task "SendDataToApi" was not set to async. Therefore, it did not wait for an results from the post, but instead ran synchronously and the control never returned to the method that ran SendDataToApi, instead it returned to the original caller - the UI.

Here is the method that is runnig the SendDataToApi task..

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(IEnumerable<TogglRow> tr)
{
    var listToExport = tr.Where(x => x.Export.Equals(true));
    var result = listToExport.ToList();
    var response = await SendDataToApi(result);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", 
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? new { message = "Record(s) were successfully stored." } : new { message = "No records selected." });
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "i'm not being redirected back to the method"? Async would cause the control to return immediately to the caller (UI). Once the call PostAsJsonAsync return, compiler will execute the code after the call (commented above). What else do you expect to achieve?

Comment: You are right about that, the control is returned to the UI. I think i was expecting the control to be returned to the method SendDataToApi() and that it would continue with the task i.e. _return response;_. And then after the task is done i would return back to where the call to SendDataToApi where made. Wich is a post method in the MVC controller.

Comment: How should I proceed to achieve this? @SBirthare

Comment: Try response.Wait() right there in the SendDataToApi method i.e. forcing call to become synchronous.

Comment: If i do: _return await response;_ inside SendDataToApi then i can se the value of response is: Id = 12, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet processed}"

Comment: Okay.. i found the reason now. The method from where i were calling the SendDataToApi was not set as async. Sorry for taking your time on this one. Thanks for your help! @SBirthare

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some fundamental misunderstandings about how all this works. MVC actions and WebAPI actions work very differently, which is why they're actually in entirely different namespaces, even though they both implement similar components.

If you need to connect to a Web API from an MVC action, you shouldn't be receiving the response as an `HttpResponseMessage`. That's a return value for a WebAPI action, similar to how a `ViewResult` is a return value for an MVC action. It has no meaning to anything in MVC. Rather, your actual response from `HttpClient`, for example, will be a string (technically a byte array) with a content type indicating that it should be interpreted as plain text, JSON, XML, etc.

Based on the content type, you'll process this response accordingly. If it's JSON, for example, then you can use something like `JObject` from `Newtonsoft.Json` (default JSON interpreter in MVC). Then, you could use this data object to construct your response for your MVC action. If you have something indicating that a redirect should be made, then the MVC action can return on of the `Redirect*` family of results. Importantly, you can't just make the redirect the response of the Web API action, because that merely affects the `HttpClient` response object.

Comment: Thanks for the information! But the problem I had was due to the method that ran the task "SendDataToApi" was not set to async . Therefore, it did not wait for an results from the post, but instead ran synchronously and the control never returned to the method that ran SendDataToApi, instead it returned to the original caller - the UI. @ChrisPratt